# How to use Regex to remove text between two strings in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have many lines like this :

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="test" tvg-logo="http://somsite.com/test.png" group-title="stars",test
Name=sun_SEASON/STAR_NOVA&title=galaxy
```

and want to change it to :

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="test" tvg-logo="http://somsite.com/test.png" group-title="stars",test
Name=sun_SEASON&title=galaxy
```

removing everything between Season/ AND &

i tried to use this search for :

```
SEASON/[^<>]+&title=galaxy
```

and replace with:

```
SEASON&title=galaxy
```

But it didnot work! could any one tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. Could you give an example of the output? Or did the RE not match anything?

Comment: Worked for me. Are you sure you chose the Regular expression option in the Replace Dialog?

Comment: Thanks for replies. I fixed it by using SEASON/*.*&title=galaxy instead of SEASON/[^<>]+&title=galaxy

Answer (score 0):

```
SEASON(/[^&]+)&title=galaxy
```

delete $1

or

```
(?<=Name=sun_SEASON).*?(?=&)
```

delete

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=SEASON)[^&]+(?=&)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This will replace by nothing (ie delete) everything that is between `SEASON` and `&`